# Who ate my rudbeckia flower leafs?

Tags: diagnosis

Somebody ate all my kale and now eating my rudbeckia leafs. It is a flower, not a veggie plant, but still seems to be tasty.
Any ideas what/who it can be and how to deal with it, please.
I am in Canada, north of Toronto area. No, I didn't check at night. There are no deer here in residential area. We closed all holes under the fence, at least I don't see any.

[image: PLANT1]

[image: PLANT2]

Comment: What part of the world are you in? Have you checked at night to see what's out there (rabbits? deer? other local wildlife?) Any toothmarks on leaves or stems, or slime trails?

Comment: add pictures please

Comment: Pictures, please!

Comment: I can't tell from the pictures but in my experience several kinds of rudbeckia (including fulgida golsturm and green wizard) and echinacea are appetising to slugs or snails, especially when small. Others including rudbeckia hirta cappuccino, seem not to be affected as much.

Comment: Can slugs and snails reach this height? I still think that it was rabbit's dinner. I found hole-entrance under the fence from my neighbor's yard. So the only prevention is full fence hermetisation.